# Database server migration and SQL Server 2008 licensing

Tags: sql-server-2008, hosting, sql, licensing, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

We currently have a dedicated server that hosts a number of websites and also has SQL Server 2008 Enterprise running on the same machine housing the databases for those websites.

We are looking to move SQL Server to a new server so it has it's own resources  rather than eating into any website resources. Is this generally considered to be a good idea?

Also, I've been informed by our hosting company that I cannot transfer my SQL Server license to the new server. I thought you could with Enterprise edition?  The new server will pretty much be like-for-like with the current server, i.e. dual quad core processors, etc...

I have a sneaky suspicion that our hosting company are trying to force us to pay a higher SQL Server license cost, considering we bought an enterprise license for £3000 p/year (approx $4500) whereas now it is £10500 p/year (approx $15750).

We could leave the SQL Server where it is and move the websites over to another machine but we don't want to go down the road of changing a whole load of DNS entries. Apparently our new server will not sit on the same domain controller unless we but an even more expensive server (almost double the price). Sounds ridiculous to me.

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Licensing questions are not something we can really help you with --   Software licensing is incredibly complex, and often situation and contract specific.  Your question needs to be taken to the company issuing the license (Microsoft), or to your corporate attorney.  If we gave you bad advice we would feel bad, but your company would be the one stuck paying the bills...

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough of a load to justify splitting the database onto another server, it's a common practice - let the web server do its web thing, and the database server do its database thing - as long as there's a need for it. It adds complexity to your infrastructure, so don't do it unless you have a need.

Nobody here is going to be able to help you with your licensing question, though. See MDMarra's link for why.